# Type of application for Symbian native app

Tags: facebook, types, symbian, native

I'm creating an application that will post to the users' wall.  It is a Symbian native app.

I know it will need to use a WebView for the OAuth2 process, but the app itself is not a web app.

What application type should I use when creating/defining the app on Facebook ?

I see these types: Website,App on facebook, Mobile web, Native iOs, Native Android and Page Tab; but none of them matches my app, which would be something like "NATIVE < other > APP".

I thought I could use "mobile web", but when selecting that type, a URL is required.

Could you please shed a light on this ?
I'm sure many people have done something similar before.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need some API to interact with facebook, it is not included by default with the Symbian SDK so you should start to search from fb, not from Symbian. Unfortunately it seems fb provides only APIs for [Android & iOS](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) so I'm afraid you'll not be able to code this as a native app in Symbian. The other JavaScript API can't be deployed directly in a widget on the phone as it requires a domain name, as you wrote.

My best guess is to create a mobile-optimized REAL website, and to create a S60 widget around it.

Comment: Thanks.  

The app only needs to post to the users' wall.

So far, I'm only using a WebView for the OAuth process.  After getting the token, I'm using a Qt's Network access manager to send post requests, and it works, so I'm not really having problems on the technical side by now.

I created the app on Fb, and didn't select any of those app types, and it works well for what I need.  I can successfully post to the user's wall from the Symbian (Qt) app.

I thought that declaring an integration type was mandatory, but it seems that it is not.

Thanks..

Any other thoughts are always welcome.